# WinRM connection refused but not to FQDN

Tags: windows, failovercluster, windows-server-2019, winrm, cluster-aware-updating

I have 2 domain joined servers running a failover cluster and I am trying to get CAU running. However, the readiness test fails because of WinRM issues.

Both servers get connection refused when using `Test-WSMan Server`, but **can** connect when using the FQDN `Test-WSMan` Server.domain

```
Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859026"
Machine="Server1.domain"><f:Message>The connection to the specified remote host was refused.
Verify that the WS-Management service is running on the remote host and configured to listen for requests on the
correct port and HTTP URL. </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-WSMan Server2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Server2:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand
```

They are on the same subnet, Windows firewalls are off and both have each other in Trusted Hosts. Any ideas why it fails to the hostname but not FQDN?

Comment: Is the domain in question also configured as a default search domain? If not your DNS resolver won't know to try to resolve `server.domain` when you attempt to resolve `server`.

Comment: It's very likely DNS related, as the first comment notes. You should also check the certificate that is used for the WinRM listener to see if it only includes the FQDN and not the short hostname. Also, did you include the FQDN and short host name of your trusted hosts in that configuration?